# GSP inclusion aka SSI (server-side includes)

Tags: grails, haml, gsp, ssi

I need the ability to include one GSP into another GSP (aka SSI).
Consider I have highly modular site with highly modular views. Web content will be spread among many tiny GSPs that will be assembled into result page. Actually I need to include HAML documents into GSP, however would be good to use GSP instuctions from HAML files (e.g. I'd embed some dynamic data into HAML, that will be later included into GSP).
Any suggestions how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a haml plugin for grails ( http://www.grails.org/plugin/haml ), but it doesn't look very updated.

As for including a gsp in another you simply call `<g:render>`on it.
Look at http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Tags/render.html for instructions.

As for how I understand your question, I don't think there is a direct way of using HAML, but anything that goes through gsp will be able to chew through `<%=bar.foo %>` or `${foo.bar}` stuff anyways, so 'dynamic' HAML is of course possible (granted that you use the plugin to compile it into gsp first).